# How to make an array of arrays that I define the dimensions with a variable?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm working in Java and I want to put in situation about the thing that I need to do.

I have an integer (for example: 4) and I need to do an array of that number of dimmensions.

If it's 1... it's easy because I can write

```
int[] v1 = new int[X];
```

in this case X doesn't matter...

but the problem is when I have a 12 for example... that it's a bad solution to use:

```
int[][][][][][][][][][][][] v2 = new int[X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X][X];
```

So my question is:
How can I make a loop for this problem and avoid to write all the cases until for example 30? because I think that that's a bad way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd probably start with not using arrays. I'd also ask myself why in heavens you need 12 dimensions (!!).

Comment: The only common base type of `v1` and `v2` would be `Object`. So how do you would use such arrays?

Comment: That's because I'm doing a kind of dynamic programming and in every case (the real case is the nim game) I need to calculate if we can win or loose... but we need to make it for save time in the things that we have previously calculated...

Comment: Side-note: Java is an OOP language. Mapping any business logic with X-dimension arrays instead of objects (through inheritance and composition, namely) looks like a bad design idea. Just in case you were going there.

Comment: The thing is that if I have calculated for example the int[3][2][5] before, I want to avoid to make again the process of recalculate it... It would be easier but we can't do it like that.

Comment: My first thought is to change your representation. Currently, it's not clear to me what int[3][2][5] would actually represent. I'm guessing it's a series of selections, but don't really know. Perhaps a hashmap would work better, where the key is a string representing the sequence of options, and the value is your int. Also, depending on the requirements, you may be able to use a smaller array and only keep values that are relevant going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the comments that using n-dimensional array with (n = 30) is a bad design idea. But if you really need it, it might be helpful:

1. You cannot create n-dimensional array dynamically.
2. You can look for `java.util.ArrayList` instead of arrays.
3. You can use 1-D dimensional array. For example:

int[][] array1 = new int[X][Y];

It will create an array for (X * Y) elements.

int[][][] array2 = new int[X][Y][Z];

It will create an array for (X * Y * Z) elements.

Above representations can also be mapped into:

```
int[] array1 = new int[X * Y];
int[] array2 = new int[X * Y * Z];
```

Say array2 = [2][5][5]; //X = 2 , Y = 5 , Z = 5

```
  0 1 2 3 4
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0

  0 1 2 3 4
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0
```

In 1-D, it would be:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 .......... 49
```

To access 3-D `array2[1][2][3]` in 1-D, calculations would be:
`array2[(1 * Y * Z) + (2 * Z) + 3 - 1]` i.e. array2[37]

This is complex and hard to implement, but it would be dynamically. I would say, you should redesign your approach.

Answer (score 0):

See [Arrays in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2). **There is no syntax in the Java programming language to "define the dimensions of an array with a variable"**.

If you want to declare a two dimensional array of integers you must write something like this in Java source code:

```
int[][] matrix;
```

If you want to declare a three dimensional array of integers you must write something like this in Java source code:

```
int[][][] cube;
```

and so on.

So, the verbatim pairs of brackets `[]` per *dimension* are a must.

Generally speaking, when you have to wrestle with something like this in a programming language, you should consider modeling your problem differently.